# Hstack doesn't work : insert a column in a file as first column

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, hstack

I try to use `np.hstack` to put a column vector as the first column of an existing array.

```
for j in range(5):

  sum_K[j] = 0.0

  l_multi_save = []
  for i in range(Num_files):

    Cl_array[i] = np.loadtxt(mypath+(Cl_files[i]))
    l_multi[i] = float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", Cl_files[i])[0])

    # Compute discrete integral <=> same than mean of D_gal_ph
    if (l_multi[i] <= l_max):
      # Save l_multi and Cl_multi
      l_multi_save.append(l_multi[i])
      Cl_multi_save[i,0:5]=np.diag(Cl_array[i,j:j+5,j:j+5])

# Part for saving multipole l and C_l
np.savetxt('Array_multipole_l.txt', l_multi_save)
Cl_multi_save2 = np.array(Cl_multi_save)
print('np.shape Cl_multi_save2', np.shape(Cl_multi_save2))
# Concatenate 2 array vertically
l_multi_save = np.array(l_multi_save)
print('np.shape l_multi_save', np.shape(l_multi_save))

#Cl_multi_save3 = np.concatenate((l_multi_save [:, np.newaxis], Cl_multi_save2),axis=1)
Cl_multi_save3 = np.hstack((l_multi_save, Cl_multi_save2))
np.savetxt('Array_Cl.txt', Cl_multi_save2[0:len(l_multi_save)], fmt='%s')
```

I get the following error:

```
np.shape Cl_multi_save2 (36, 5)
np.shape l_multi_save (36,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_main.py", line 112, in <module>
    Cl_multi_save3 = np.hstack((l_multi_save, Cl_multi_save2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in hstack
  File "/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 344, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

I don't understand why I get this error. However, dimensions seems to be right (1 column of 36 elements and 5 columns of 36 elements).

I have also tried with `np.concatenate`:

```
Cl_multi_save3 = np.concatenate((l_multi_save [:, np.newaxis], Cl_multi_save2),axis=1)
```

but it doesn't work too.

What might be wrong in my Python script?

Comment: First, we don't need all this code (especially since it isn't complete and runnable). You can reproduce the problem with data like `Cl_multi_save2 =np.ones([36, 5])` without the need for all the rest.


You need to make the shape of `l_multi_save` = `(36, 1)`. You can do that with `np.expand_dims(l_multi_save, axis=1)`.

Comment: What is `l_multi_save.shape`?

Comment: @hpaulj it seems to be: `np.shape l_multi_save (36,)`

Comment: Yes, that's a 1d shape, 36 elements.  It isn't  "1 column with 36 elements", which would be (36,1).  With the right shape `hstack/concatenate` can make a (36,6) array, with 1+5=6.

Comment: @Mark . Thanks for your help. `p.expand_dims(l_multi_save, axis=1)` did the trick ! I thought that a shape of `(36,)` should be enough but apparently, I need to have explicitly a shape of `(36,1)` : I didn't know that it would create issues with hstack/concatenate. Best regards